# What should I do in springboot if I use a post request with only one parameter?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

No use of map and bean, what is a good solution?

How to get the orderId better

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitTail", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Object generateTailOrder(String orderId) {

}
```

Comment: *How to get the orderId better*. What do you mean by 'better'. What *exactly* is wrong with the code as is??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PathVariable if you can add orderId somewhere in URL. Take care of API standards.

Example: `/orders/{orderId}/submitTrail`
By doing this your API will be more informative and should not be invoked without orderId.

Comment: But our team doesn't use restful style api.

Comment: I think no, as you refused map and bean also. in that case, use whatever you mentioned in question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitTail/{orderId}", method = 
RequestMethod.GET)
public Object generateTailOrder(@PathVariable String orderId) {

}
```

OR

```
@GetMapping(value = "/submitTail/{orderId}")
public Object generateTailOrder(@PathVariable String orderId) {

}
```